# Cant drop database nor create database

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, terminal

When I run mysql as root and run `SHOW DATABASES;` it shows that I have a `one_db` database, but when I run `DROP DATABASE one_db;` it outputs the following error:

```
ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'one_db'; database doesn't exist
```

I then try to `CREATE DATABASE one_db;` and outputs this error:

```
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'one_db'; database exists
```

How can I delete this database now?

---

### ## Here is the whole session (logged in with root) ##

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| one_db             |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP DATABASE one_db;
ERROR 1008 (HY000): Can't drop database 'one_db'; database doesn't exist
mysql> CREATE DATABASE one_db;
ERROR 1007 (HY000): Can't create database 'one_db'; database exists
```

Comment: @amdixon sorry, copied the wrong error log, I've updated the question

Comment: suggest redoing this in one mysql session and copy-pasting entire session ( ie. with the two commands and responses )

Comment: try restarting mysql

Comment: @amdixon I've restarted mysql and nothing changed

Comment: can you add the response of `mysqlcheck --repair one_db`

Comment: @amdixon `mysqlcheck: Error: Couldn't get table list for database one_db: Can't read dir of './one_db/' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)`

Comment: @amdixon is there anyway to clean all mysql database data? I've uninstalled and reinstalled mysql (I'm using homebrew) and the databases are still there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82402/discussion-between-amdixon-and-gespinha).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To fix, can manually cleanup the mysql files relating to the `one_db` database :

**manual cleanup process**

> 1. Find the datadir path for mysql by running ( at mysql shell ) :
>
>    ```
>      show variables where Variable_name ='datadir';
>    ```
> 2. Stop mysql server
> 3. remove the one_db directory under the 'datadir'
> 4. restart mysql server and verify database one_db is not present

Comment: It's a very nice solution (+1).